# Vim, removing blank and commented lines in one regex

Tags: regex, vim

I want to remove blank and commented lined at one time. I already found the similar question regarding  removing blank lines, so for blank lines I use:

```
:g/^$/d
```

and for commented lines:

```
:g/^#/d
```

I'm curious is there any way to merge these regex in one? Something like

```
:g/^[$#]/d
```

but obviously it doesn't work in vim.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can try this command:

```
:g/^\(#\|$\)/d
```

Or

```
:g/\v^(#|$)/d
```

---

- `$` matches literal '$' inside [...] (type `:help /$` for help)
- `\|` is for alternation
- `\v` is very magic (minimal backslash escape)

Comment: only one thing I would suggest here is to send the deleted lines to the blackhole register by adding an underscore after the `d` operator. Like so: `:g/\v^(#|$)/d_` This will be noticeably faster if the file is huge. Also the deleted comments are not likely needed for subsequent pastes so why keep them

Comment: @PeterPerháč when you do that, is possible to use the undo?

Comment: @JoelFrancoGuzmán yes, I believe this will depend on your undo configuration (how much data it can hold, if you have a HUGE file). You should be able to just try this out on some dummy text file. See for yourself if you can undo. But I believe you can.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of solving this is keeping the non-commented lines:

`:g!/^[^#]/d`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following :

```
:g/^$/d | /^#/d
```

The `|` is there to combine multi command at the same time.

Comment: you cannot pipe to `g`, but `g` applies across all commands in a pipeline. So this is better-written as `:g /^$/d | /^#/d`

Answer (score 4):

You can combine regex patterns with the "or" operator: `\|`, eg:

```
:g/^\(#.*\|$\)/d
```

Though, in this particular case, you actually just need to specify that `#.*` is optional, eg:

```
:g/^\(#.*\)\?$/d
```

Finally, be aware that you can chain together most commands with VIM's (not regex's) "pipe" operator, also `|`, eg:

```
:g /^#/d | /^$/d
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on kevs answer:
If anyone would also like to delete the comments in config files that are tabbed,
for example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
    ...
```

You can try this:

```
:g/\v^(#|$|\t#)/d
```